# threadsafe re-entrant queue using peek

Tags: c#, thread-safety, queue, peek

My basic problem is needing to process items from a queue immediately if the queue is empty, or add an item to the queue and leave if there is an item already being processed.

I'm trying out a technique that uses peek to simplify things and am wondering what gotchas there may be that could get in the way.  Thanks!

```
    void SequenceAction(Action action) {
       bool go = false;

       lock (_RaiseEventQueueLock) {
          _RaiseEventQueue.Enqueue(action);
          go = (_RaiseEventQueue.Count == 1); 
       }

       // 'go' can only be true if queue was empty when queue 
       //  was locked and item was enqueued.
       while (go) {
          #if naive_threadsafe_presumption 
          // Peek is threadsafe because in effect this loop owns
          //  the zeroeth item in the queue for as long as the queue 
          //  remains non-empty.
          (_RaiseEventQueue.Peek())();

          #else
          Action a;
          lock (_RaiseEventQueueLock) {
             a = _RaiseEventQueue.Peek();
          }
          a();
          #endif   

          // Lock the queue to see if any item was enqueued while
          //  the zeroeth item was being processed.
          // Note that the code processing an item can call this 
          //  function reentrantly, adding to its own todo list
          //  while insuring that that each item is processed 
          //  to completion.
          lock (_RaiseEventQueueLock) {
             _RaiseEventQueue.Dequeue();
             go = (_RaiseEventQueue.Count > 0); 
          }
       }
    }
```

Comment: wouldn't `go` always be `true` after `Enqueue`?  How would you know that the Peek doesn't execute an action twice?  You seem to have a race condition there--nothing is ensuring multiple threads aren't calling `Peek` around the same time...

Comment: Don't forget to lock around using Peek! It is not safe.

Comment: Oops, there goes Leningrad, sorry boss.  Thanks usr and Jim, I should have read the class documentation more closely and/or should have thought it through better.

Comment: See my updated answer for a possible fix.

Comment: But won't Monitor.TryEnter() happily succeed when called by the same thread?  What got me into this mess was a thread that re-acquired a lock and executed an action itself re-entrantly while the prior action was still being processed by itself. I don't care what thread performs the actions as long as each action is completed before the next.

Comment: @ewd: It would be better if we discussed this in the comments to my answer. And, yes, `Monitor.TryEnter` would happily succeed when called by the same thread ... but that can't happen. There are two separate locks, and the thread isn't acquiring them re-entrantly. Unless, of course, one of the actions can end up queuing other actions. That would definitely throw a wrench in the works. The more I think about this, the more I recommend going with a producer/consumer relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    // If action already in progress, add new
    //  action to queue and return.
    // If no action in progress, begin processing
    //  the new action and continue processing
    //  actions added to the queue in the meantime.
    void SequenceAction(Action action) {
       lock (_SequenceActionQueueLock) {
          _SequenceActionQueue.Enqueue(action);
          if (_SequenceActionQueue.Count > 1) {
             return;
          }
       }
       // Would have returned if queue was not empty
       //  when queue was locked and item was enqueued.
       for (;;) {
          action();
          lock (_SequenceActionQueueLock) {
             _SequenceActionQueue.Dequeue();
             if (_SequenceActionQueue.Count == 0) {
                return;
             }
             action = _SequenceActionQueue.Peek();
          }
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your `Peek` is not threadsafe. Adding an item to the queue could cause the backing store (an array, eventually) to be resized. I imagine the queue is implemented in a circular buffer, with head and tail indexes for insertion and removal.

So imagine what happens if there are, say, 16 items in the queue. Insert is at 8, and Remove is at 9. The queue is full. Then this happens:

1. Thread A calls Peek, retrieves the Remove index (9).
2. Thread A gets swapped out.
3. Thread B calls Enqueue and sees that it has to grow the queue.
4. Thread B allocates a new array of 32 items and copies data from the existing array. Data is copied in order, starting at Remove and wrapping around.
5. Thread B sets Remove to 0 and Insert to 16.
6. Thread A gets its next timeslice and returns the item at position 9.
7. You have just processed an event out of order, and you will end up processing it again.
8. Worse, you will remove the item at position 0 without processing it.

You *might* be able to solve that problem with:

```
Action nextAction;
lock (_RaiseEventQueueLock)
{
    nextAction = _RaiseEventQueue.Peek();
}
nextAction();
```

I wouldn't stake my professional career on it, though. I'd suggest using a [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) and a producer/consumer design.

**Possible fix**

It occurs to me that the following should do what you intended.

```
private readonly object _queueLock = new object();
private readonly object _processLock = new object();

void SequenceAction(Action action)
{
    lock (_queueLock)
    {
        _RaiseEventQueue.Enqueue(action);
    }
    if (Monitor.TryEnter(_processLock))
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Action a;
            lock (_queueLock)
            {
                if (_RaiseEventQueue.Count == 0) return;
                a = _RaiseEventQueue.Dequeue();
            }
            a();
        }
        Monitor.Exit(_processLock);
    }
}
```

Comment: @ewd: If this can be re-entrant, then you can replace `_processLock` with a `ReaderWriterLockSlim`, with lock recursion disabled. Replace the `Monitor.TryEnter` with a `TryEnterWriteLock`, and handle the `LockRecursionException` that occurs on an attempted recursive acquisition of the write lock.

Comment: @JM: My basic problem is needing to process items from a queue immediately if the queue is empty, or add an item to the queue and leave if there is an item already being processed. The motivation for the OP solution was to overcome the 'wrench in the works' of actions triggering actions that could cause a train wreck if performed before completion of an action-in-progress. The OP solution performs correctly and with the addition of the lock around the Peek(), so much the better. Thanks again.